# Regex matching up until comma

Tags: regex

I have some input strings where I want to just get the city names (Brighton, Singapore, Austin, San Francisco)

```
Brighton, United Kingdom
Singapore
Austin, TX, USA
San Francisco, CA, USA
```

I've tried doing this regex `(.*),?` but it matches the whole string, disregarding the comma. How can I only match up till the first comma if it exists?

Comment: Use a non-greedy quantifier: `(.*?),?`

Comment: Try using `^([\w ]+)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
(?m)^[^\r\n,]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9flAGe/1).

**Details**

- `(?m)^` - start of a line
- `[^\r\n,]+` - one or more chars other than CR, LF and a comma.

Comment: If there is anything wrong with the answer, please drop a comment. Please bear in mind that this regex is a valid solution for the OP problem, and your current scenario may differ from OP.

Comment: Again, what is wrong with this solution?